# No complet command outputs in mac codeBlocks

Tags: c++, macos, codeblocks

So i have the program bellow, but the console keeps showing me only my first cout even if i input n, I need some help
        #include

```
using namespace std;

void DivizoriCresc1(int n, int d)
{
    cout << " ceva";
    if(d > 0)
    {
        DivizoriCresc1(n, d - 1);
    }
    if(n % d == 0)
    {
        cout << d << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "n =";
    cin >> n;
        cout << " ceva";
    DivizoriCresc1(n, n);
        cout << " ceva";

    return 0;
}
```

Last login: Wed Nov 21 16:11:42 on ttys000
MacBooks-MacBook-Pro:~ macbook$ /Users/macbook/Desktop/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/macbook/CodeBlocksProject/tema1/bin/Debug/tema1 
n =50

Process returned -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)   execution time : 1.856 s
Press ENTER to continue.

MacBooks-MacBook-Pro:~ macbook$

Comment: Your program crashs due to a division by zero error on `if(n % d == 0)`. You should replace the line`if(d > 0)` by `if(d > 1)`

Comment: Or move the second `if` inside the first `if` block...

Comment: oh ty, i didnt expect this little think